# Axis labels for graphs?

Tags: gnuplot, rotating

I'd like to use gnuplot 2d graphs in my LaTeX document. I need to have a LaTeX expression in the title of y-axis, for example `$\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$` rotated vertically and centered at the axis.

What would be the best way to do it?

Can I use LaTeX expressions in gnuplot? I know one can use Greek symbols in gnuplot.

Comment: 2nd comment in this forum post helps http://old.nabble.com/How-to-rotate-y-axis-label-in-LaTex-output-td25782085.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search brought up [this tutorial](http://www.gnuplot.info/files/tutorial.pdf).  Depending on what type of plot you intend to make, you may also be able to use [pgf/tikz interface](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/gnuplot/) to gnuplot.

I see now after more careful reading of your question that you are interested in rotated and centered text.  In that case, if you have a recent version of gnuplot, you can try the new `tikz` terminal.  There is an example available [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-tikz-terminal/).

Comment: that's what i was using. but i want to take a png image (some of the graphs are contour plots). and put labels on the side for axis.

Comment: I did not notice that you want to rotate the labels, I just concentrated on the part of your question where you ask about using LaTeX expressions in gnuplot.  You can rotate latex boxes using the `graphicx` package, but using the tikz terminal will give you more options.  To produce a png image, you can start with pdf from pdflatex, and convert it to png.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package for your plots. It uses Gnuplot as back-end.